# $ \int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0} \cos ^{\frac{3}{2} }\left(2 \theta \right) \cos \left( \theta \right) d\theta $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$ \int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0} \cos ^{\frac{3}{2} }\left(2 \theta \right) \cos \left( \theta \right) d\theta $$

This integration above I tried to solve it by and get

$$ \int^{\frac{\pi }{4} }_{0} \left( 1-2\sin ^{2}\left( \theta \right) \right) ^{\frac{3}{2} }d\sin \left( \theta \right)$$

and I tried to evaluate the power but I find this is useless.

My question is: *how I can get this integration in the closed form?*
  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Define $\sin{\phi}=\sqrt{2} \sin{\theta}$.  Then the integral is equal to

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi \, \cos^4{\phi} = \frac{3 \sqrt{2} \pi}{32}$$

NB

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi \, \cos^{2 n}{\phi} = \frac1{2^{2 n}} \binom{2 n}{n} \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Comment: your solution gives approximately 0.265, when Wolfram Alpha returns an approximate value of 0.614. Edit: I can't tell what is the correct approximation. Anyone else have another software to check other than mathematica?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: I was off by a factor of 2 (forgot to multiply by $\pi/2$ rather than $\pi$).  But Mathematica agrees with me.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: would help if I put the $\pi$ in as well.  Forgive me for my sloppiness.

Comment: I disagree. When I do N[Integrate[Cos[θ]^(5/2), {θ, 0, Pi/4}]] in Mathematica I get 0.673368 . I'm still not wholly convinced that your "simplification" is correct

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: the problem is for $3/2$.  It is hard to see, but zoom in, or look at the script.

Comment: You are correct. I was mistaken in that I missed the fact that it was $\cos(2\theta) and not \cos(\theta). I apologize, and I completely agree with you now.

Comment: SO NEAT. Great fan of your solutions here and the ones on your blog, thank you for your efforts. ^_^

Comment: @user257567: it is just a generalization of the result I obtained through the substitution, just so you know where the result comes from.  My point was that we can write down the integrals of even powers of cosines over $[0,\pi/2]$, so that the substitution I provided reduced the integral to something well known.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. And what $\large{ NB} $mean?

Comment: @user257567: "Nota Bene."  Latin for "Note well," or less literally, "take note."

Comment: @RonGordon you learn me mathematics and Latin :).  Great thanking for your efforts sir